# Unable to change gateway info in fiddler

Tags: configuration, fiddler

Is it possible to change the gateway info in fiddler?
In Fiddler whne I look at Help > About Fiddler link, I see the gateway info to be not the same as my IE; however I am not sure how I can change the gateway info in Fiddler.

I think as a result of this; I can not see any web sessions in fiddler.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The Gateway info in Fiddler's About dialog shows the upstream gateway, which is calculated from the IE settings it adopts on startup. If you see a difference, it's probably because the hostname was resolved to an IP address.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- thanks for the input. The issue that I see is this: in my organization the proxy pac file to use are different based on the network/access we have. The PC that I am on came with an OS image which points to say "http://abc/x.pac" for my access to work I have to change the proxy to "http://xyz/y.pac". The problem is no matter what I do fiddler keeps on picking the "http://abc/x.pac" which surprises me. I just want to figure our which location fiddler picks this from? In my IE I see the proxy configuration as I expect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
accidentally I came across on how to start fiddler to track my http requests today.
This is what I had to do,

Step 1. Change the proxy settings by going to IE > Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings
Here disable the "Automatic Configuration" by unchecking both the proxy options and then go to "Proxy server" section and check the option "Use proxy server for you LAN" option. In the Address text field enter 127.0.0.1 and in the port field enter 8888.

Step 2. Start Fiddler as an administrator.

And fiddler starts to work.
This is in a scenario where you are behind a firewall.

HTH